How to pass and handle parameters Durable functions v4 javascript?
I'm very new with durable functions V4 in javascript but I cannot get this activity to run properly. I always get an error as apparently I'm not passing in the Instance ID correctly.
What am I doing wrong here? The tutorial page on the microsoft website was of no use.
Here is the code:
df.app.orchestration('reportOrchestrator', function* (context) {
   try {
       const instanceId = context.df.instanceId; // Get the current orchestration's instance ID
       context.log(`Orchestration instance ID: ${instanceId}`);

       const lsFile = { instanceID: instanceId }; // Pass instanceID in an object
       const token = yield context.df.callActivity('TokenManager', { instanceID: instanceId }); 

context.log(`Token retrieved: ${token}`);


return token;

  // const result = yield context.df.callActivity('PipelineQuery', { token });

  } catch (error) {
    return error.message;
    context.log(`Error in orchestration: ${error.message}`);
    throw error;
  }
});
df.app.activity('TokenManager', {
   handler: async (context) => {
        const log = context.log;

         const lsFile = context.getClient().instanceID; // Direct input passed from the orchestrator

if (!lsFile || !lsFile.instanceID) {
    //log("InstanceID is missing or undefined");
    throw new Error("InstanceID is missing or undefined,", context);
}

const instanceID = lsFile;
//log(`Orchestrator Instance ID is ${instanceID}`);

let functionID = "POST Reports Orchestrator";

try {
    // Make the POST request to retrieve the token
    const tokenResponse = await axios.post(logicAppURL, {
        requestType: "GET_TOKEN",
        functionID: functionID,
    });

    // Check if token was successfully retrieved
    if (tokenResponse.data && tokenResponse.data.token) {
        //log("Token successfully retrieved");
        return tokenResponse.data.token;
    } else {
        //log("Token could not be retrieved. Functions will generate their own token");
        await mandrillGeneralError(log, "Error retrieving token on POST Reports Orchestrator Token Manager function app in Azure.");
        return ""; // Return empty token if retrieval fails
    }

} catch (error) {
    //log(`Error retrieving token: ${error.message}`);
    await mandrillGeneralError(log, `Error retrieving token: ${error.message}`);
    throw error; // Throw the error so it's logged properly by Durable Functions
}
}
  });


In logic app url what type of url you are using?

I tried your code and got the same error: incorrect Instance ID.
This occurs because the instance ID changes each time it is run. The instance ID is the unique identifier for the instance and if you don’t specify this parameter, the method uses a random ID.
I have referred to this document for Durable Functions in JavaScript
The below code is for retrieving a token in durable functions and to this git link for full code .
const axios = require('axios');

async function generateToken(logicAppURL, instanceID) {
    if (!instanceID) {
        throw new Error("InstanceID is missing or undefined.");
    }

    console.log(`Orchestrator Instance ID is ${instanceID}`);

    try {
        const tokenResponse = await axios.post(logicAppURL, {
            // requestType: "GET_TOKEN", // Uncomment and customize if needed
            // functionID: functionID,   // Uncomment and customize if needed
        });

        if (tokenResponse.data && tokenResponse.data.token) {
            console.log("Token successfully retrieved");
            return tokenResponse.data.token;
        } else {
            console.log("Token could not be retrieved. Returning an empty token.");
            return "";  
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error retrieving token: ${error.message}`);
        throw error;  
    }
}
const logicAppURL = "<Your Logic App URL>";
const instanceID = "your-instance-id";
generateToken(logicAppURL, instanceID)
    .then(token => console.log(`Generated Token: ${token}`))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));





Output:


I have referred to this git to pass and handle parameters durable functions.
In your code I see logicAppURL(or) anyURl using post /get request by passing the instance ID to an activity function named TokenManager and FunctionId.
In general, if Instance ID changes every time do not use Instance ID as a parameter and the FunctionId property provides a unique identifier for an Azure Function, which is assigned by the host.
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const functionId = context.executionContext.functionName;
    context.log(`Function ID: ${functionId}`);




This identifier remains stable across multiple invocations of the same function, allowing for consistent tracking and logging.

Refer to this Msdoc1 and Msdoc2 for more details about Instance ID and Function ID.

    const invocationId = context.executionContext.invocationId;

    context.log(`Invocation ID: ${invocationId}`);


Additionally, refer to this SO to get the identifier of the Logic App and check the above fields of this while passing in post request.
The alternative way is to use only the url in logicAppURL requests for post/get requests without using functionID, Instance ID.
I have referred to link to get a token from logic app.

const axios = require('axios');
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const df = require('durable-functions');

const tenantId = 'tenantId'; 
const clientId = 'clientId';
const clientSecret = 'clientSecret'; 

async function getAccessToken() {
    const url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
    
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    params.append('client_id', clientId);
    params.append('client_secret', clientSecret);
    params.append('scope', 'https://management.azure.com/.default');

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(url, params, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
        const accessToken = response.data.access_token;
        console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
        return accessToken; 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving access token:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }
}

const activityName = 'durableHello1';

df.app.orchestration('durableHello1Orchestrator', function* (context) {
    const input = context.df.getInput();
    const outputs = [];
    const accessToken = yield context.df.callActivity('getAccessTokenActivity', null);
    
    for (const city of input.cities || ['Tokyo']) {
        outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity(activityName, city));
    }

    return { greetings: outputs, accessToken };
});

df.app.activity(activityName, {
    handler: (input) => {
        return `Hello, ${input}`;
    },
});
df.app.activity('getAccessTokenActivity', {
    handler: async () => {
        return await getAccessToken();
    },
});

app.http('durableHello1HttpStart', {
    route: 'orchestrators/{orchestratorName}',
    extraInputs: [df.input.durableClient()],
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        const client = df.getClient(context);
        const body = await request.json();
        const instanceId = await client.startNew(request.params.orchestratorName, undefined, body);
        context.log(`Started orchestration with ID = '${instanceId}'.`);
        return client.createCheckStatusResponse(request, instanceId);
    },
});




